# Is there a way to get an image that you search using Pixabay and send it using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, pixabay

I am using the Pixabay API to search for an image, then I want my discord.py bot to say it. However, I don't know what function you have to call to be able to get the image so the discord bot can actually send it in an embed.
Here is my current code.

```
@bot.command(name='otter', help='Generates a random otter!')
async def otter(ctx):
    r = requests.get('https://pixabay.com/api/?key=keyisherebutforprivacyreasonsiamremovingitlol&q=otter&image_type=photo')
    r = r.json()
    for item in r['hits']:
        print(item['type'])
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Otter test', color=discord.Color.from_rgb(226, 22, 31))
        embed.set_image(url=item[random.choice(range(0, 5))]) # The problem is here, as I took the image bit away and the embed sent fine.
        embed.set_footer(text='Powered by pixabay.')


    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Pretty much, it just prints out: photo over and over, which is good, because that means the search works. As a test, I removed the set image part, and the embed sent fine, so I know it is a problem with the embed.set_image. If anyone knows the correct way to actually get the image and send it, I would be really appreciative. Thanks! I get no error message in the console, either.

Comment: I'm assuming the item list is full of URLs for pictures?

Comment: I print out r['hits] and get nothing in the terminal, and the bot doesn't say anything, pretty much just stops everything after.

Nevermind, just forgot to put the actual api key in haha

Comment: Let me try print out r

Comment: Have you tried printing out `r` by itself to see what keys are available? And to make sure that the json isn't empty in the first place

Comment: You're way ahead of me haha

Comment: Okay I replaced the API key with the actual api key, let me try run it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213742/discussion-between-oblique-and-diggy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're grabbing the right content from the response (`r`). If you run into any 404 errors, you can check if the url contains image extensions (`.jpg`, `.png`, etc.).

For future reference, to easily visualise jsons, you can use [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) website.

Good luck with the otters!